# Run system command from jupyter lab extension?

Tags: javascript, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I would like to write an extension for jupyter lab for viewing netCDF files (.nc), a common format for scientific data. Basically, I would like the plugin to run `ncdump -h <filename>` on the selected file and paste the contents into a new window. I am a total javascript newb, so maybe this whole endeavor is too much for me.

I am following [these jupyer lab docs](http://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/developer/extension_dev.html), and I have succesfully registered my plugin to open `.nc` files. Now, I need to run `ncdump -h` on the systems shell. To do this, I gather that I need to import the `child_process` library from Node. To do this, I put

```
import {exec} from 'child_process';
```

in my `src/index.ts` package,
but unfortunately, I get this error

```
src/index.ts(9,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'child_process'.
```

I assume this happens because jupyter lab is not running server-side at all so none of the Node packages are available. Is there some other way to run a system command and capture the output from a jupyter lab extension?